# User can not interact with Custom Sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts, user-permissions

I am creating a vacation application web part. As an admin I can interact with the web part buttons. I have created several standard users for testing purposes. The problem is when I as a standard user try to click the "create application" button the web part shows the error message "Sorry, this site hasn´t been shared with you". I have created two groups. "vacation Admins"-Can approve and deny application and the standard users I put in the "MySite members group". "MySite members group" has Edit premission. Giving it Full Control didnt help.

Anybody have any idea´s?

Answer (score 0):

This problem didnt cause any truble in the end.